# JS/bookmarklet to replace characters in the URL with some other characters, but retain domain name

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, kirby

When the bookmarklet is clicked, I need the URL, such as this:

```
https://example.com/test/page1/page2/page3/final page
```

To be replaced with:

```
https://example.com/panel/pages/test+page1+page2+page3+final-page
```

If it isn't clear, the domain remains the same, but then after it is **/panel/pages/**, followed by the same original page structure, but with **+** instead of **/**. Finally, if **final page** has a space (not all of them do), a **-** is used.

Not every URL I want this for has three pages before the final one. Some have just one or two. So, it would need to apply to all of them somehow.

The idea here is that the second link is used for editing the page, and the first is the live page. I want an easy way to open the page for editing. Ideally, the new URL would open in a new tab.

I'd love some direction, considering I'm a total newb at this.

Comment: `window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/panel/pages/' + window.location.pathname.replace(/\//g,'+')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```js
(function(loc) {
  loc.href = `${loc.protocol}//${loc.host}/panel/pages/${
    loc
      .pathname
      .slice(1)
      .replace(/\//g, "+")
      .replace(/(\s|%20)/g, "-")
  }`;
})(window.location)
```

This creates a redirect to...

1. `protocol` is `http:` or `https:`
2. Adding `//` in between the domain and host
3. The page host name
4. We go to the hardcoded `/panel/pages/`
5. `loc.pathname` gets everything including and after the `/` in the URL
6. Because it includes the leading `/`, we must remove it so it does not become `+` as well with `.slice(1)`
7. Then we replace all `/`s with `+`
8. Replace all spaces (in the URL it's encoded as `%20`)

*Bookmarklet-ready code:*

```
javascript:(function(l){l.href=`${l.protocol}//${l.host}/panel/pages/${l.pathname.slice(1).replace(/\//g,"+").replace(/%20/g,"-")}`})(window.location)
```

Comment: This works flawlessly on the two types of URLs I was concerned about. Thank you so much!